# Mongoengine... How can I compare two fields?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

For example..

```
class Example(Document):
    up = IntField()
    down = IntField()
```

and.. I want to retrieve documents whose up field is greater or equal to down. 
But.. this is issue.

My wrong query code would be..

```
Example.objects(up__gte=down)
```

How can I use a field that resides in mongodb not python code as a queryset value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: not possible. Something like WHERE A = B in SQL is not doable in an efficient way in MongoDB (apart from using the $where clause which should be avoided).

Comment: @WebEngineer yup. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D

Answer (score 0):

this may be what you wanted::

db.myCollection.find( { $where: "this.credits == this.debits" } );

have a look at: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

but I donot know how to use it in mongoengine.

Comment: get it. the mongoengien do this like below:   Example.objects.where("this.a >= this.b")